# Datepart for time between (instead of Convert date)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to use Datepart to select rows which have time between like 12:20 and 15:50 using datepart, because Convert date to time is unusably slow for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for example you can use this

```
DECLARE 
    @min FLOAT = CAST(CAST('19000101 12:20' AS DATETIME) AS FLOAT),
    @max FLOAT = CAST(CAST('19000101 15:50' AS DATETIME) AS FLOAT)

SELECT 
    *
FROM table
WHERE CAST(DateField AS FLOAT) - FLOOR(CAST(DATEFIELD AS FLOAT)) BETWEEN @min AND @max
```

**But this is actually not a solution!!!**

The best way is to introduce 1 more calculated column as

```
NewColumn AS DATEPART(HOUR, DateColumn)*100+DATEPART(minute, DateColumn)
```

Create index on it and use in where clause

```
WHERE NewColumn BETWEEN 1220 AND 1550
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming time periods on the same day;

```
...
where cast(fld as time) between '12:20' and '15:50'
```

Comment: Index scan in better case, table (clust. index) scan in worst case. Isn't it? The question was about performance.

Comment: Yes indeed, he didn't mention he could redesign the table so I assumed its not an option.

Comment: If not - there are no any options about performance - just create an index on date field and sql server will use index scan. But you completely right about assuming...

Answer (score 0):

The only alternative is t use a CTE. Tested it and it works.

LH = Low hour
HH - High Hour
LM - Low minute
HM = High minute

```
;WITH CTE_LH AS 
(
SELECT *  
FROM DateTable 
WHERE (DATEPART(HOUR, DateCol) >= 12)
)
, CTE_HH AS 
(
SELECT *  
FROM CTE_LH 
 WHERE (DATEPART(HOUR,DateCol) <= 15 )
)
,CTE_LM AS 
(
SELECT *  
FROM CTE_HH 
WHERE (DATEPART(MINUTE,DateCol) >= 20 )
)
,CTE_HM AS 
(
SELECT *  
FROM CTE_LM 
WHERE (DATEPART(MINUTE,DateCol) <= 50 )
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_HM;
```

Comment: Brackets do not matter in a chain of `AND` operations. It does not look like this condition is capable of handling the times with minutes below 20 or above 50, e.g. 13:05 or 14:58.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. The brackets are useless with AND. Updated my answer.