# SQL Server 2012 Time Range Check?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, time

What is the smart way to determine if the current time is between the 59th minute of this hour and the first minute of the next hour, using pure TSQL on MSSQL 2012?

I do not want to cut off the time from "now", I want to cut off the date and just do a time calculation.

This gets me kind of close : [Datepart for time between (instead of Convert date)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575519/datepart-for-time-between-instead-of-convert-date) but not exactly since I need to calculate based on current time and not table values.

The following might help illustrate if the server is currently in "the bad time" and should return a value of '1'

```
14:58:59 ,  Should not be considered in the "bad time"
14:59:00 ,  Should be considered in the "bad time"
14:59:04 ,  Should be considered in the "bad time"
14:59:57 ,  Should be considered in the "bad time"
15:00:02 ,  Should be considered in the "bad time"
15:01:26 ,  Should not be considered in the "bad time"
15:02:00 ,  Should not be considered in the "bad time"
15:02:01 ,  Should not be considered in the "bad time"
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

This code works, but I am sure this can be done more efficiently. All recommendations welcomed. Thanks again.

```
declare @now time = ( select cast( sysutcdatetime() as time  ))
declare @floor time = ( select dateadd( minute , 59 , ( dateadd(hour,datediff(hour,0,@now),0) ) ) )
declare @ceiling time =(  select dateadd( minute , 2 , @floor ) )
if ( @now > @floor and @now < @ceiling )
begin
    select 1 as bit
end
select @now , @floor , @ceiling
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "between the 59th minute ... and the first minute"? Maybe you could list some examples, like `14:58:59, 14:59:00, 14:59:04, 14:59:57, 15:00:02, 15:01:26, 15:02:00, 15:02:01`, and indicate which of those should be included? Currently the description is ambiguous since `BETWEEN` may or may not mean inclusive on each end of the range, and whether the end range is 00:01, 00:01:59, or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace `@dt` as required:

```
declare @dt datetime = '20130419 21:59:01'

select case when datepart(minute, @dt) in (59,0)
            then 'Minute is between 59 and 1'
            else 'Minute is NOT between 59 and 1'
       end myMinute
```

Answer (score 3):

```
IF DATEPART(MINUTE, SYSDATETIME()) = 59
    PRINT '59th minute';
```

Answer (score 1):

MINUTE(@dt)=59 OR MINUTE(@dt)=0